# Wrap a tag around multiple instances of a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to wrap multiple instances of a string found in html around a tag (span or abbr) using pure JS. I have found a way to do it by using the code:

```
function wrapString() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/string/g, ‘<tag>string</tag>');
};
```

but using this code messes with a link’s href or an input’s value so I want to exclude certain tags (A, INPUT, TEXTAREA etc.).

I have tried this:

```
function wrapString() {
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
        if (allElements[i].tagName != "SCRIPT" && allElements[i].tagName != "A" && allElements[i].tagName != "INPUT" && allElements[i].tagName != "TEXTAREA") {
            allElements[i].innerHTML = allElements[i].innerHTML.replace(/string/g, ‘<span>string</span>');
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn’t work as it gets ALL the elements containing my string (HTML, BODY, parent DIV etc.), plus it kept crushing my browser. I even tried with JQuery's ":containing" Selector but I face the same problem as I do not know what the string's container is beforehand to add it to the selector.

I want to use pure JavaScript to do that as I was planning on using it as a bookmark for quick access to any site but I welcome all answers regarding JQuery and other frameworks as well.

P.S. If something like that has already been answered I couldn't find it...

Comment: In general, any method that involves `innerHTML` will necessarily destroy and recreate parts of the DOM and have significant consequences (will kill all event handlers, unnecessarily slow, that kind of thing) so should probably be ruled out. A more disciplined solution using classic DOM methods to do a DFS of the page is a better option.

Comment: @Jon Since I'm a beginner in JS and DFS (haven't heard of it until you mentioned it) do you mind to elaborate on your advice? I figure DFS would give me all the final nodes first so I can check their contents, right? What if the string isn't contained in the last element?

Comment: It will give you all nodes, including intermediate ones. You can also exclude certain nodes from consideration immediately (e.g. you probably don't need to look into a `<canvas>` etc) so you might not even consider *all* nodes. Zord's answer below is based on this same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite complicated problem actually (you can read [this detailed blog post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/) about it).
You need to:

1. recurse on the dom tree
2. find all text nodes
3. do your replace on its data
4. make the modified data into dom nodes
5. insert the dom nodes to the tree, before the original text node
6. remove the original text node

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7y7k/3/).
And if you still need tagName based exclusions, look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7y7k/2/)

The code:

```
function wrapInElement(element, replaceFrom, replaceTo) {
    var index, textData, wrapData, tempDiv;
    // recursion for the child nodes
    if (element.childNodes.length > 0) {            
        for (index = 0; index < element.childNodes.length; index++) {
            wrapInElement(element.childNodes[index], replaceFrom, replaceTo);
        }
    }
    // non empty text node?
    if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(element.data)) {
        // replace
        textData = element.data;
        wrapData = textData.replace(replaceFrom, replaceTo);
        if (wrapData !== textData) {
            // create a div            
            tempDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
            tempDiv.innerHTML = wrapData;
            // insert
            while (tempDiv.firstChild) {
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(tempDiv.firstChild, element);
            }
            // remove text node
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
    }
}

function wrapthis() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    wrapInElement(body, "this", "<span class='wrap'>this</span>");
}
```